# Lambda function cant connect to redshift: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: python, ssl, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I understand there are a few questions related to these issues. I have seen them but could not find the correct solution.

I am using AWS Secret Manager to store the credentials and right now trying to connect with AWS Redshift using AWS Lambda Function.

Here is my lambda.py

```
import json
import boto3
import base64
import psycopg2
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def get_secret(secret_name):
  try:
      session = boto3.session.Session()
      client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name='xx')
      get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value( SecretId=secret_name )
      secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
      secret = json.loads(secret)
      

      return secret 
    
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  s = get_secret('secretname')
  
  conn = psycopg2.connect(database = s['xx'], 
                            user = s['username'],
                            password = secret['password'],
                            host = secret['host'], 
                            port = secret['port']
                           )
                            
  print('connected')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("""Select * from table1;""")
  rows = cur.fetchall()

  for row in rows:
      print(row[0])
```

ERROR: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::ffff:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "xxxx", database "xxx", SSL off

I am using psycopg2.

I have tried inserting, " sslmode = 'require'", not working.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: database firewall is blocking but not sure why

Comment: Can you verify if your lambda is in VPC and sg has proper route access

Comment: is it got to do with my psycopg2?

Comment: port should be 5439 is it accepting in that port?

Comment: Double check the username and password, could be wrong credentials, try to print in the console as a test.  As @Prashanna mentioned, check if the security rules (inbound and outbound) allows the port 5439 for TCP protocol.

Comment: All information is correct and the port is fine too

Comment: "errorMessage": "sslmode value \"require\" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in\n", when i put sslmode ='require'

Comment: Denise - Have you figured out how to resolve this issue. I am also blocked on this task